# image/graph looks bad in template

Tags: graphics, luatex

I have some problem with a graph packet in LaTeX. http://www.texample.net/tikz/examples/drawing-graphs/ is the package I'm using.

It worked fine for me to compile the example from the webbpage but the graph looks very bad when I copied it to my thesis document. I am using the template idamasterthesis.cls in my document with can be downloaded  from https://www.ida.liu.se/edu/templates/latex/idamallar-latest.tar

MVE:

```
\documentclass[cropmarks, frame, english]{idamasterthesis}

\usepackage{flafter}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{verbatim}
\usetikzlibrary{graphdrawing}
\usetikzlibrary{graphs}

\abstract{%
\S\ This is the abstract.
}

\begin{document}

%\layout

\makeintropages

\chapter{Introduction}

\begin{figure}
\begin{tikzpicture}[>=stealth, every node/.style={circle, draw, minimum          size=0.75cm}]
   \graph [tree layout, grow=down, fresh nodes, level distance=0.5in, sibling     distance=0.5in]
{
    A -> {
      B -> { A -> {C}, C -> {D} ,D },
      C -> { A, B -> {C  ,D} },
      D -> { C }
    }
};

\end{tikzpicture}
\caption{this is the text for the img}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

This is the picture of how the graph looks in my thesis:

[image]

Please note that the graph libary needs to be compiled by lualatex!

Comment: Please give us a MWE of your code showing your problem.

Comment: Sorry, but what is "MWE"?

Comment: [Minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228)

Comment: A Minimal Working Example (MWE) is a small peace of code which produces the error or unexpected behavior

Comment: Ok, I got it! I made an edit.

Comment: The first error i get: `inputenc` not designed to work with LuaTeX`. Never trust a class, that loads inputenc with any option.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You missed the `\usegdlibrary{trees}`.

[image]

For the `inputenc` error, if you only need English, you can remove lines `88` and `130` of the class file and make sure you change all non-English letters, like `ö`, in the class file also. For a more elegant solution to this, you can use the `etoolbox` [package](http://ctan.yazd.ac.ir/macros/latex/contrib/etoolbox/etoolbox.pdf), which provides commands like `\pretocmd` with which you can temporarily change some parts of the class file without actually changing any thing in the `class` file.

The syntax is simple:

```
\pretocmd{<command>}{<code>}{<success>}{<failure>}
\apptocmd{<command>}{<code>}{<success>}{<failure>}
\patchcmd{<command>}{<code to replace>}{<code>}{<success>}{<failure>}
```

Comment: I feel so stupid now. Have wasted so long time on this stupid problem. Thank you so much! Could I ask you if also get the   inputenc error that Johannes_B got? I get it as well(but I guess that is of topic...

Comment: If I use etoolbox, can I keep the non-english letters?